# Scikit-learn R2 always zero

Tags: scikit-learn, regression

I'm trying to test my Scikit-learn machine learning algorithm with a simple R^2 score, but for some reason it always returns zero.

```
import numpy
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

prediction  = numpy.array([0.1567,  4.7528,  1.1260,  0.2294]).reshape(1, -1)
training    = numpy.array([0, 3, 1, 0]).reshape(1, -1)

r2          = r2_score(training, prediction, multioutput="raw_values")
print r2
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

This is a single four-part value, not four separate values.  How do I get proper R^2 scores?

Comment: Right now you are calculating r2 for each _pair_ of values in your arrays. Remove the `.reshape` method from each numpy array and the `r2_score` function will return a single r2 value for the two arrays

Comment: I have the `.reshape()` because that's how the `.fit()` and `.predict()` functions use and return arrays.  Is the `r2_score()` different for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to calculate the r2 value between two vectors you should just pass two one dimensional arrays. See the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html)

In the example you provided, the first item is compared to the first item, but note you only have one list in each the prediction and training, so it is calculating R2 for 0.1567 to 0, which is 0, then it calculates it for 4.7528 to 3 which is also 0 and so on... It sounds like you want the R2 for the two vectors like the following:

```
prediction = numpy.array([0.1567,  4.7528,  1.1260,  0.2294])
training = numpy.array([0, 3, 1, 0])

print(r2_score(training, prediction))
0.472439485
```

If you have multi-dimensional arrays you can use the `multioutput` flag to determine what the output should look like:

```
#modified from the scikit-learn example
y_true = [[0.5, 1], [-1, 1], [7, -6]]
y_pred = [[0, 2], [-1, 2], [8, -5]]
print(r2_score(y_true, y_pred, multioutput='raw_values'))
array([ 0.96543779,  0.90816327])
```

Here the output is where the first item of each list in y_true is compared to the first item in each list of y_pred, the second item to the second and so on

Comment: But none of the machine learning algorithms output (n,) arrays or 2D Python lists; they all output (1, n) arrays.  Do I need to convert them just for the `r2_score()`, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It sounds like the issue you are running into is that the shape of the output  array of a regressor does not match the shape that is required for the `r2_score`. Can you provide an example of this and show what is not working as expected? I ran a regressor and compared the predicted values to the actual values using `r2_score` with no issues