# Why is scikit-learn r2 score zero?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I have a problem where I've got a training dataset where all the Y values are 0.75 and my model is predicting scores for each row as a regression - but when calculating r2 it's zero and I can't see why

I found only 1 other similar question ([Scikit-learn R2 always zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447635/scikit-learn-r2-always-zero)) but applying the answer given there isn't helping me, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

What I have is this:

```
df["Score"] = 0.75
Y = df["Score"] 
df_valid = df.drop(["Score"],1)

y_pred = model.predict(df) #model is random forest regressor from sklearn 

prediction = np.array(y_pred)
training = np.array(Y)

print(prediction)
print(training)


[0.77279743 0.18169051 0.81874664 0.75440987 0.67748983 0.56747803
 0.66120282 0.5829188  0.73471978 0.57745964 0.48272321 0.65313173
 0.805028   0.63791055 0.49677642 0.64341235 0.55456506 0.52329214
 0.67690119 0.79450821 0.63378986 0.69522612 0.69802982 0.6719472
 0.67977281 0.29016943 0.56192242 0.16265814 0.57813068 0.72598279
 0.50255597 0.77138968 0.53745061 0.527479   0.67161703 0.64326146
 0.5299367  0.79977403 0.73527391 0.50858258 0.74660319 0.72315073
 0.71879784 0.55134538 0.61812615 0.64722909 0.67055658 0.68687499
 0.73416035 0.4781765  0.74878142 0.5773583 ]
[0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75
 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75
 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75
 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75]
```

both `prediction` and `training` are numpy arrays of the same shape - am I missing something else?

When I try `print(r2_score(training, prediction))` it gives me 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**R2** score will be 0 when `y_predicted` or `y_true` is always the same value. In your case, you have always the same `y_true`.

Going deeper to the formula, **R2** is calculated:

[image]

And SStot is calculated as:

```
SStot= y_true - ymean
```

In your case, your y_true - y mean will be always 0, since (0.75-0.75=0). So When calculating **R2** you finding problem **dividing by 0**.

On the other hand, if you have the same value for y predicted, SSres and SStot would be the same, and your R2 would be also 0.

Consult this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-coefficient-of-determination-r2-score/) for more information of how calculate **R2**, it is pretty well explained

Comment: Thank you for this, I will look into that link - am I right to then not use r2 to evaluate the model in this case? For example I have results for mean square error and max error that I could just use instead

Comment: Yes! Don't use r2 for this data. Use other types of measure like you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

R-squared is basically the proportion of variance explained by the model, you can see the first line of [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) :

> In statistics, the coefficient of determination, denoted R2 or r2 and
> pronounced "R squared", is the proportion of the variance in the
> dependent variable that is predictable from the independent
> variable(s).

Your actual or observed values consist of only one value, there is no variance to speak of, so why you want to measure R^2?

You might be trying to check or measure something else how well your model can predict values that have a similar observed value, but taking R^2 on this subset does not make sense